# Using std::make_pair with std::string (non rvalue reference problem)

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

```
std::pair<Url, std::string> UrlParser::parse()
{
    return std::make_pair({ extract_scheme(), extract_hostname(), extract_port(),
                 extract_path(), extract_filename() }, host_ip_);
}
```

The `host_ip_` variable is defined as

```
std::string host_ip_;
```

I get

```
UrlParser.cpp:91:64: error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, std::string&)'
   91 |                  extract_path(), extract_filename() }, host_ip_);
```

The problem is on the `host_ip_` variable. If it's an `std::string`, then what's the problem in returning it?

I found [c++11 rvalue references in `std::make_pair`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470843/c11-rvalue-references-in-stdmake-pair/24470966) which explains that we can't call `std::make_pair` with non-rvalue references, so I tried

```
std::make_pair({ extract_scheme(), extract_hostname(), extract_port(),
                     extract_path(), extract_filename() }, std::move(host_ip_));
```

but I get

```
error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, std::remove_reference<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&>::type)'
   91 |                  extract_path(), extract_filename() }, std::move(host_ip_));
```

By the way, why in the link provided, `int` is an rvalue reference but `const int` is not?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431495/initializer-list-and-template-type-deduction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with passing `host_ip_` as lvalue or rvalue to [`std::make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair); both should work fine. Instead, the braced-init-list `{ extract_scheme(), extract_hostname(), extract_port(), extract_path(), extract_filename() }` makes [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) for the 1st template paramter of `std::make_pair` failing because of [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

> 6. The parameter P, whose A is a braced-init-list, but P is not `std::initializer_list`, a reference to one (possibly cv-qualified), or a reference to an array:

You can pass a `Url` explicitly,

```
return std::make_pair(Url{ extract_scheme(), extract_hostname(), extract_port(),
//                    ^^^
             extract_path(), extract_filename() }, host_ip_);
```

or specify the template argument explicitly.

```
return std::make_pair<Url>({ extract_scheme(), extract_hostname(), extract_port(),
//                   ^^^^^
//                   specify the 1st template argument, left the 2nd one to be deduced
             extract_path(), extract_filename() }, host_ip_);
```

Comment: I couldn't find a reason for this thought. The compiler knows the type that needs to be returned, so it knows it's a pair where the first element is an Url. Why it's not possible?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs The problem is the calling of `make_pair` itself fails, template argument deduction won't consider return value. Consider if you call `make_pair` solely like `std::make_pair({ extract_scheme(), extract_hostname(), extract_port(), extract_path(), extract_filename() }, host_ip_);`, the types must be deduced by the calling itself, which has nothing to do with how the return value is assigned.

Comment: nice, now I understand. C++ does not try to bind types into the places where they'll used. For example, if I return something, it does not try to look into the return type. This is a choice of design for the language. Rust on the other side does look and thus could infer the type

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Yes, allowing that means the behavior of same statement might change when the return value is used in different ways. That won't happen in C++.